# Assets pipeline on heroku : how to manage 2 environments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have 2 environments for my app on heroku: staging and production, and I'm using Rails 3.1 assets pipeline.

I have set a custom config.action_controller.asset_host property to make my assets fetched from cloudfront on http://assets.myapp-staging.com or http://assets.myapp.com

The issue is that on Heroku, assets are always precompiled with the production environment. Which means that all the urls present in my css or js files target http://assets.myapp.com even in staging.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is to do one of two things:

1) **Use the new user-env-config labs add-on** which makes your environment variables available during the slug compilation phase.

To use this simply:

```
$ heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp
-----> Enabling user-env-compile for myapp... done
WARNING: This feature is experimental and may change or be removed without notice.
```

For more information on this see here:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

**or**

2) **Don't use those assets.**  With the Asset Sync gem you can run the compilation of the assets once the application has been spun up in it's evironment.  This will then sync your assets to S3.

For more information on this, check out: 
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31

Comment: Thanks, I also found the the asset_sync gem and started to go this way. But I really prefer your first solution, I'll let you know today if it works!

Comment: It works like a charm. Just had to figure out that I needed this plugin : https://github.com/heroku/heroku-labs